# Angular 4 DatePipe with current timezone

Tags: angular, timezone, timezone-offset, date-pipe

So I have a component where I need to display dates received from an endpoint, but these dates are stored in UTC I believe. So I've been trying to use DatePipe to display the date in a better format, but I also need the timezone to match the current user's timezone.

```
<span>{{data[col.field] | date: 'short'}}</span>
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<span>{{data[col.field] | date: 'short':new Date().getTimezoneOffset()}}</span>
```

but I believe this isn't possible and I also think `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` doesn't give me the right format since DatePipe expects something like `'+0900'`. Has anyone run into something similar?

Comment: you can use ngx-moment : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment

Comment: Is there no way around it using datepipe? If not I guess moment would be my last resort.

Comment: Seems like a little custom pipe magic would do wonders... You could do it how you want but imho it'd be too much code golf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following:

Add in *component*

```
addZero(number, length){
    var str = "" + number
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0'+str
    }
    return str
}

readableTimeZone(offset) {
    return ((offset<0? '+':'-') + addZero(parseInt(Math.abs(offset/60)), 2) + addZero(Math.abs(offset%60), 2));
}
```

*HTML*

```
<span>{{data[col.field] | date: 'short':readableTimeZone(new Date().getTimezoneOffset())}}</span>
```

**Other solution**

*Component*

```
getFormattedTimeZone() {
  return new Date().toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+.*)/)[1].split(' (')[0].replace(/[A-Z]+/,'')
}
```

*HTML*

```
<span>{{data[col.field] | date: 'short':getFormattedTimeZone()}}</span>
```

Comment: Hmmm, this seems to give me the right timezone offset format, `-0600`, but the date is still not being formatted, it still shows `4/2/18, 6:05 PM` when it should be `4/2/18, 12:05 PM`

Comment: you can refer Angular documentation for that I guess.

Comment: I think that have a mistake on the set of the sign, it show be `offset>0? '+':'-'`